# Redirection in htaccess for the same domain

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect from one url to another in the same domain, domain is www.example.com

From `http://www.example.com/ca/ceca/callback` to `http://www.example.com/es/ceca/callback`

I tried this but it doesn't work.

> `# Redirect url to other url in the same domain
>   Redirect /ca/ceca/callback http://www.example.com/es/ceca/callback`

**Maybe it worths to mention that the url is not really loaded in a browser but it is requested by a payment system to get a response from our website.**

Comment: If you want the user to redirect, send the [R] flag, if you are using for internal redirect purposes, just remove that flag, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)ca/(.*)$ $1/es/$2 [R]
```

What

```
^(.*)ca/(.*)$
```

Does is that it searches entire request url for "ca/" pattern, and since you want to preserve stuff after ca, we enclose it in braces. Braces make sure it gets stores in variables.

Next we rewrite the url as $1, everything matched by first expression in first set of braces, that is anything before ca, then we write "es" and then append stuff from second set of braces, stores in $2. The [R] flag is to send the redirect response header to client with the new url.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I need to only redirect /ca/ceca/callback and not all /ca/*

Comment: In that case match (.*)ca/(ceca/callback)$ and rewrite it with  $1/es/$2